# Encrypt SQL server data using machine key and SQL CLR code - SQL Express

Tags: c#, sql, .net, encryption, aes

I am investigating whether it is possible to transparently encrypt data in a SQL Express database using SQL CLR code to carry out the encryption and decryption.

I currently have a system where certain fields need to be encrypted/decrypted, and the cryptography is being carried out in .Net code on the client. Performance is quite appalling - loading 1000 records, each with 4 fields each is taking up to a couple of minutes, using AES.

I am using Entity Framework, so I'm not wanting to use stored procedures - therefore I can't pass a password in as a param to a stored procedure.

Is it feasible to encrypt/decrypt data using the .Net machine key? (i.e. implement AES in SQL Clr, which will use the machine key as the key for encryption). In this case, if the database is copied to another machine, it won't be possible to view real data, as the machine key will be different.

I understand that if a user can access the database and log in using (eg.) SSMS they'll be able to select * from what they like, however I will rely on SQL Server security to prevent this. The main issue is I can't secure the mdf and ldf, and if a user gets access to these I don't want them to be able to view the data.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server supports butch of procedures to encrypt data. For example [EncryptByPassPhrase](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190357%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

[Here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3483931/SQL-Server-2005-Security---Part-3-Encryption.htm) you may find manual for using encryption in SQL Server 2005.